# how to combine two unsigned 32bit integers to 64bit integer in php?

Tags: php

I have two unsigned 32 bit integers that I need to combine to make one long integer or a string it does not matter if it is in string format as long as I have the number. for example:

low: -589298671

high: 4

thanks!

Comment: Use BCMath functions() ?

Comment: Or [bitwise operators](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.bitwise.php) if PHP is compiled for larger integers and you're on the right platform.

Comment: Aren't 64 bit integers platform dependant?

Comment: @Ian: They are. On 32-bit systems, PHP uses 32-bit integers.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up finding a solution in this [article](http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2007/03/27/integers-in-php-running-with-scissors-and-portability/).

it has solved my problem perfectly also will work on any system. it's a great piece of code.